# How does this theme move the post navigation location in the DOM based on the screen size?

Tags: themes, navigation

I'm talking about [this](https://preview.arraythemes.com/paperback/2015/10/27/when-technology-gets-too-smart/) theme preview.

If you inspect the post and look at the `<nav class="post-navigation">` element and resize the viewport at the `769px` breakpoint, it moves after/before the sidebar.

I tried looking in the developer tools at their `paperback.js` file but didn't find anything. It doesn't look like it's done with CSS either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done through [paperback.js](https://preview.arraythemes.com/paperback/wp-content/themes/paperback/js/paperback.js?ver=1.0)

Lines 201-242:

```
// Navigation
    $(window).on("resize load", function() {

        var current_width = $(window).width();
        var post_navs = $('.single .post-navigation');

        // If width is below ipad landscape
        if (current_width > 1024) {
            // Explore drawer
            drawerOpenToggle.click(function(e) {
                $('#big-search').focus();
                return false;
            });
        }

        // If width is below iPad size
        if (current_width < 769) {

            // Move the post navs above the sidebar
            $(post_navs).insertAfter('#comments');

        } else {

            // Reset drawers on resize
            $('.site-identity .toggle-sub').remove();

            // Return the post navs
            $(post_navs).insertAfter('#page');

            // Adjust column height on resize
            equalHeight();
        }
    });
```

Line 214 declares `post_navs` for `.single .post-navigation`.

Then Line 229 moves it after `#comments` when it's below 769, otherwise moves it after `#page`